# Adding springframework.data.cassandra to pom.xml stops tomcat logs to appear in console

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data

As soon as I add springframework.data.cassandra to pom.xml tomcat logs stops appearing in the eclipse console. Here's screenshot before adding cassandra: [image: pom.xml before adding cassandra]

[image: logs before adding cassandra]

[image: pom.xml after adding cassandra]

[image: logs after adding cassandra]

You can see that the debug, trace and all other logs disappear. I have tried this in a fresh project also without using any code which depends on cassandra. I am using log4j.properties. Here's a screenshot of that:

[image: log4j.properties]

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. do you see same output (in 1st and 2nd case) also in your log file?

Comment: 2. try to check all maven dependencies (something like mvn dependency:tree) if you find any possibly coliding dependency (another version of logging - especially slf4j can be sensitive on that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the real answer (addition to what @sodik said).

The problem was with jcl-over-slf4j conflict with version 1.7.7 which was part of spring.data.cassandra and spring.data.commons.

To resolve the issue "right click in the Resolved dependencies" pane in the pom.xml dependency hierarchy and choose "Exclude Maven Atrifact".

IMP: Don't forget to update the Maven project (just cleaning and re-installing doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Add the corresponding slf4j *bridge* and *binding* jars to your classpath. In your case, you should add `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar` to bind to `log4j` and (optionally) `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` as a bridge for Spring logs (Spring actually uses JCL).

**Important:** If you 'route' Spring logs to `slf4j` by adding this last jar, you should also exclude JCL transitive dependency from all your Spring dependencies.

**Note**: when running tomcat, you'd better place all `slf4j` dependencies in tomcat/lib directory and set their scope as **provided** in your pom.xml files.

Please see [here](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) and [here](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) for further details.

Comment: Tried with no luck. Still the same problem. Sorry for the late reply.